# Chain rule when $u$ is a fucntion of $x$ and $y$ and both $x$ , $y$ are fucntions of $u$ and $v$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

Find $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ where $u$ and $v$ are functions of $x$ and $y$ $\bigg($ $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ $\bigg)$ and $x$ and $y$ is of the form, $x = f(u,v), y=g(u,v)$.

This was in an exam and had multiple choices for answers. Some answers contained $\partial f$ and $\partial g$ terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use implicit differentiation on $x=f(u,v)$, considering $u$ and $v$ as functions of $x$ and $y$, to obtain (differentiation w.r.t. $x$):
$$1 = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\color{blue}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}
+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\color{red}{\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}}$$
Doing the same (differentiation w.r.t. $x$) for $y=g(u,v)$ gives:
$$0 = \frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\color{blue}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}
+ \frac{\partial g}{\partial v}\color{red}{\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}}$$
Together this gives you a system of two linear equations in the unknowns $\color{blue}{u_x}$ and $\color{red}{v_x}$; you can solve for $u_x$ and compare with the multiple choice alternatives.

Addendum: if you use implicit differentiation w.r.t. $y$ as well, you can also find $u_y$ and $v_y$. You may recognize a common denominator appearing in all these partial derivatives: this is the **Jacobian** of the transformation between both pairs of variables.

Comment: sure that $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}=1$, but can we put $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=0$?

Comment: You consider $x$ and $y$ to be independent variables (same for $u$ and $v$).

Comment: I had the same problem,  can we put $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=0$. Thanks for clarifying.